# Initializer blocks

Tags: java

Do System.out.println() statements always get executed? Suppose I have

```
class c2
{
{
 System.out.println("initializer");
}
public static void main(String a[])
{
System.out.println("main");
 c2 ob1=new c2();
}
}
```

Then why will the "initializer" statement be also printed. Is it any constructor statement?

Comment: sopln? I always call them "syso". Is that a standard shorthand?

Comment: Did u try? what was the outcome?

Comment: In this case yes. Instance initializer blocks are executed every time you create an instance of the class.

Comment: something wrong with bracers

Comment: why dont you just run and see

Comment: Surely you can take a minute to check the outcome?

Comment: Why bother asking when you could have run this program yourself and see the result?

Comment: That dude is running some quiz program. Hope there are prices for people who win.

Comment: Voted to close this down. Is this really a problem that OP could not solve? It just takes a min to get answer of this by running the code.

Comment: @ZiyaoWei don't know about you, but I call it System.out.println()...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes , it will print :

```
main
initializer
```

Your initializer will be called once you call the constructor of the `c2`.Your default constructor for class `c2` implicitly looks like :

```
c2() {
  {
    System.out.println("initializer");
  }
}
```

Refer the JLS for [12.4.2. Detailed Initialization Procedure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2).

Comment: @imulsion Just to highlight the block.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will. If you create an instance of the class (`c2 ob1=new c2();`) the default constructor will execute the command. That program will also output "main", as in the main method a new command is called.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of a **Initializing Instance Member Block**

When you create the c2 object, the sysout command in the brackets will also be executed.
You can add initialization code like this as long as it is enclosed within a block.

See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html

**Why would you use it?**

> The Java compiler copies initializer blocks into every constructor.
>   Therefore, this approach can be used to share a block of code between
>   multiple constructors.

Comment: You can share code between constructors more much more easily by a) calling one ctor from another and/or b) by calling methods (eventually static methods) from the ctor. This is much more reusable than initializer blocks.

Comment: Ease in some cases is purely subjective and also depends on the specific problem your trying to solve. Also depends on programming level, problem, coding style, and knowledge. "Therefore, this approach **can** be used to share a block of code between multiple constructors." This is from the official oracle documentation.

Comment: I added the comment _not_ because something you've said is wrong. But if someone will read this answer later, it _could_ be understood in a way that initializer blocks are _recommended_ or at least widely used for that purpose. I just wanted to clarify, that this just a technical possibility but not a common nor a recommended one.

Comment: @A.H. It could also be argued that if you share code between constructors explicitly via a chain of `this()` calls, it becomes a right chore to figure out which constructor does what, where an initializer block clearly communicates "this always happens". Not like you should write classes that complex that figuring out how initialisation works becomes difficult; but then, if you write code that's readable at a macro level, it's a bikeshed argument to debate which of these two functionally equivalent constructs is "better".

Comment: @A.H. Also, "the answer could be understood as a recommendation" is a much stronger claim than "the answer does not go on a tangent to exclude the possibibility of being understood as a recommendation", where the latter seems to be the case.

Answer (score -1):

Yes but it would be better practice to have that code in a method, in this case in c2 constructor.